# Excel VBA Range Offset not working consistently

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to look through a document for the one cell that contains "Reconciler Notes:" and then merge & align cells A through I of the row below the found cell. Here's my code:

```
Set s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Find("Reconciler Notes", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

If Not s Is Nothing Then 
Set e = s.Offset(1, 0) 
Set z = e.Offset(0, 8)

With Range(e, z)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter 
End With

End If
```

When I watch the variables, e comes out fine but then z returns "Line is not an executable statement". If I remove the code for Set z, then the Set e returns the same error. Been wracking my brain for days - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in a blank workbook with "Reconciler Notes" added to a cell.

Comment: Same here. Side note: are you maybe looking to [resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Resize) `e` before merging it?

Comment: `With s.Offset(1).Resize(1, 9)`

Answer (score 0):

"Line is not an executable statement" will occur if you right-click > run to cursor while your cursor is on a non-executable line, like a blank line or a comment. Try right-clicking on the `With Range(e, z)` line instead of the blank line

[image]
[image]

[image]